# docker service started, but daemon still has not been started in RHEL 7 VM

Tags: docker, daemon

For some reason, I hosted docker in a VM (RHEL 7).

After installed docker 1.8, the service can be started correctly, but when I call docker info or some related command, it tells me that daemon has been started.

But when I start docker daemon manually by command "docker daemon", it can be started smoothly and just with a warning, and it works well to run or search a image.

So currently my issues is once I start the docker daemon in one putty session, I can execute docker related operation through another session, but once I closed the session with daemon started, all ended.

Searched a lot, but seems have not found a good solution yet. Thanks ahead.

Attached some environment information:

docker daemon:

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker daemon<>
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "devicemapper"
INFO[0000] Option DefaultDriver: bridge
INFO[0000] Option DefaultNetwork: bridge
WARN[0000] Running modprobe bridge nf_nat br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: WARNING: Module br_netfilt
, error: exit status 1
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.
............................ERRO[0000] Error unmounting device 292a999f0e633020b435c6199958d4fccb1f4a3ca0a3ccc428d4fccb1f4a3ca0a3ccc42e38cba208a137c2
INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization
INFO[0000] Docker daemon                                 commit=d12ea79 execdriver=native-0.2 graphdriver=device
INFO[0032] GET /v1.20/images/json
INFO[0040] GET /v1.20/containers/json?all=1
292a999f0e633020b435c6199958d4fccb1f4a3ca0a3ccc42e38cba208a137c2INFO[0096] GET /v1.20/containers/292a999f0e63302
INFO[0151] GET /v1.20/containers/292a999f0e63/json
```

docker info:

```
*[root@localhost ~]# docker info
Containers: 14
Images: 15
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:4-1073748960-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop1
 Metadata file: /dev/loop2
 Data Space Used: 3.016 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 104.4 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 3.351 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.144 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.93-RHEL7 (2015-01-28)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.0 (Maipo)
CPUs: 10
Total Memory: 9.609 GiB
Name: localhost.localdomain
ID: U5OY:WDSL:5IP3:2UFW:XYP6:3B2J:WJS4:6QY6:QDKL:MIFN:G452:QI33
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled*
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the firewalld disable the docker container use something ports when you start docker. try it execute:

`systemctl stop firewalld & systemctl restart docker`